# BLOCK checkout.onepage.review makes checkout slow?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

When I go to the checkout, it takes a long time. I used the AOE Profiler to profile and figured that one row takes up all the time. It is **BLOCK checkout.onepage.review**. It happens in my theme and also in the default theme. There is no checkout extension installed, so its the default checkout process. Any ideas where to continue looking?

**Magento 1.9.3.2**

Comment: Do you have any observers or 3rd party modules?

Comment: Yes, there are some 3rd party extension

Comment: Well what happens if you disable them? also, if you are using the AOE profiler you should be able to drill down into that block and see what part of the email is bottle-necking